# PowerShell Regex with VSS command

Tags: regex, powershell

i wanted to select specifically select the "Writer name","Writer Id" and "Writer Instance Id" for the output of "vssadmin list writers", i needed some help on how to go about it using regex and create powershell objects, can some one help

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $list = vssadmin list writers
PS C:\Windows\system32> $list
vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
(C) Copyright 2001-2012 Microsoft Corp.

Writer name: 'Task Scheduler Writer'
   Writer Id: {d61d61c8-d73a-4eee-8cdd-f6f9786b7124}
   Writer Instance Id: {1bddd48e-5052-49db-9b07-b96f96727e6b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'VSS Metadata Store Writer'
   Writer Id: {75dfb225-e2e4-4d39-9ac9-ffaff65ddf06}
   Writer Instance Id: {088e7a7d-09a8-4cc6-a609-ad90e75ddc93}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Performance Counters Writer'
   Writer Id: {0bada1de-01a9-4625-8278-69e735f39dd2}
   Writer Instance Id: {f0086dda-9efc-47c5-8eb6-a944c3d09381}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'System Writer'
   Writer Id: {e8132975-6f93-4464-a53e-1050253ae220}
   Writer Instance Id: {cb8da305-5a18-4bf9-91e6-981bcf836c7b}
   State: [9] Failed
   Last error: Timed out
```

Comment: Did you already try inspecting `$list` by piping it to `Get-Member`? Maybe you won't even need Regex.

Comment: Its a string type, no powershell objects, PS C:\Windows\system32> $list | gm


   TypeName: System.String

Name             MemberType            Definition
----             ----------            ----------
Clone            Method                System.Object C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want objects, something like this will do the trick:

```
$cVssOutput = vssadmin list writers

# Creating an empty collection.
$cVssWriters = @()

foreach ($line in $cVssOutput) {
    $cNameValue = $line.Trim() -split ': '

    if ($cNameValue[1] -ne $null) {
        if ($cNameValue[0] -eq 'Writer name') {
            # New writer. Initializing a new object.
            $oVssVriter = New-Object PSObject
        }

        # Formatting and adding properties.
        $sName = $cNameValue[0] -replace " ", "" 
        $sValue = $cNameValue[1] -replace "'", ""
        $oVssVriter | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $sName -Value $sValue

        if ($cNameValue[0] -eq 'Last error') {
            # All properties in place.
            # Adding the object to the collection.
            $cVssWriters += $oVssVriter
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can select the properties you need, for example:

```
$cVssWriters | % { $_.WriterName }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander, i tried another solution too and it worked, posted it below

Comment: You're welcome! And as always there's more than one way to get the same result. )

Answer (score 0):

I tried this an it worked, not that simple but it worked.

```
$vssarray = @()
$list = vssadmin list writers
$listnew = $list -replace "\s","" | Select-String "Writername:","WriterId:","WriterInstanceId:" 
foreach ($vss in $listnew)

{

$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{

'WriterName'= (((((($vss | select-string "Writername:") -replace "Writername:","")) -replace "'","")))
'WriterId'= (((((($vss | select-string "WriterId:") -replace "WriterId:","")))) -replace '\{,\}')
'WriterInstanceId' = (((((($vss | select-string "WriterInstanceId:") -replace "WriterInstanceId:",""))))-replace '\{,\}')

}

$vssarray += $obj

}

$writerinstanceid = $vssarray | ?{$_.writerinstanceid -ne $null } | select writerinstanceid | select -ExpandProperty writerinstanceid
$WriterId = $vssarray | ?{$_.writerid -ne $null } | select WriterId | select -ExpandProperty writerid
$writername = $vssarray | ?{$_.writername -ne $null } | select writername | select -ExpandProperty writername

0..($writerinstanceid.Length-1) | Select-Object @{n="WriterName";e={$WriterName[$_]}},@{n="WriterId";e={(($WriterId[$_]).TrimStart("`{")).TrimEnd("`}")}},@{n="WriterInstanceid";e={(($WriterInstanceId[$_]).TrimStart("`{")).TrimEnd("`}")}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me.

```
$Writers = @(vssadmin list writers | Select-String -Context 0,4 '^writer name:' | 
Select @{Label="Writer"; Expression={$_.Line.Trim("'").SubString(14)}}, 
   @{Label="WriterID"; Expression={$_.Context.PostContext[0].Trim().SubString(11)}},
   @{Label="InstanceID"; Expression={$_.Context.PostContext[1].Trim().SubString(20)}},
   @{Label="State"; Expression={$_.Context.PostContext[2].Trim().SubString(11)}},
   @{Label="LastError"; Expression={$_.Context.PostContext[3].Trim().SubString(12)}})
```